# Mysql natural order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a column:

```
1 TB
1.5 TB
2 TB
3 TB
16 GB
32 GB
64 GB
128 GB
256 GB
320 GB
500 GB
512 GB
750 GB
```

and I want 1 TB, 1.5 TB, 2 TB 3 TB to appear at the end.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have just `TB` and `GB`:

```
order by (case when col like '%GB' then 1
               when col like '%TB' then 2
          end),
         col + 0 asc
```

This orders first by GB.  The second converts the column to a number and sorts by the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  `columnName` 
FROM
  `Table` 
ORDER BY RIGHT(`columnName`, 2) ASC,
  `columnName` ASC
```